# How can I create a makefile for my C project?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

this is my c project it is exactly simple linux shell I run this program in linux
I want make makefile for my program .I want simple makefile 
learn me how can i make it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARR_SIZE 1<<16
void sig_had(int signo)
{
    puts ("This is my signal handling ..!");

}
void parse_args(char *buffer, char** args, 
                size_t args_size)
{
    char *buf_args[args_size]; 
    char **cp;
    char *wbuf;
    size_t i, j;

    wbuf=buffer;
    buf_args[0]=buffer; 
    args[0] =buffer;

    for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*cp != NULL) && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
            break;
    }

    for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
        if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
            args[j++]=buf_args[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARR_SIZE];

    int status;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t child_pid;
    signal(SIGCHLD,sig_had);
    while(1){
        printf("COMMAND ");
        fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);
        parse_args(buffer, args, ARR_SIZE); 

            child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid){

            child_pid = wait(status);

        } else {
            execvp(args[0], args);


        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)

Comment: Please please do some reading before asking.... show at least some effort in your question, too....

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any Makefile at all for that. Assuming that your source file is stored as `foo.c`, just run

```
make foo
```

The default Makefiles will kick in, executing

```
cc foo.c -o foo
```

Answer (score 4):

OK... if you want to generate a makefile for this then type:

```
all: yourfilename.c
    gcc yourfilename.c -o yourexename
```

Into a file named "Makefile" (no extension) placed the same as your `.c` file(s). Then run `make` in that directory.

**Note 1:** white space is important in Makefiles, the command to build `gcc ...` should be 1 `<tab>` indented

**Note 2:** this is just a simple example, you can (should) modifiy the build command with your own flags. `-Wall` would be a good one to put in.

**Note 3:** Makefiles are a huge topic. Make sure you read up about them: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: +1 for a clear, straightforward answer.  It might be nice to recommend use of `-Wall` in the gcc invocation too.

Comment: all: project.c   gcc project.c -o project . and I named file as makefile.c that is right ?

Comment: @Suzana - You name it as "Makefile" (no extension). Also note that white space is important in Makefiles.

Comment: missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop  error

Comment: @Suzana - Yes, that's a tab. You can't tab in the answer box so I used 8 spaces. Sorry I didn't clarify that.

Comment: @Suzana - remove any old `.o` files or previous executables that you've built. Then try `make all`, if it still fails there's something wrong with locations/names of files or spacing in your makefile

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no `make` configured settings prior,

```
# gcc to compile source files.
CC = gcc
# linker is also "gcc". may be something else with other compilers.
LD = gcc
# Compiler flags go here.
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
# Linker flags go here. 
LDFLAGS =
# list of generated object files.
OBJS = hello.o
# program executable file name.
EXEC = exec

all: $(EXEC)

# rule to link the program
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
      $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC)

hello.o: hello.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c hello.c
```

As long as you have only .c file creating one executable binary you no need anything more.